# OSX Command Line Readln equvilent

Tags: c, macos

I'm just starting playing with some programming for OSX, and trying to create a simple command line app but I can't seem to find a good guide. Basically I want to know how to get some user input for example ask the user their age etc.

Comment: Do you want full GNU readline support or simply want `fgets()`-type behavior?

Comment: fgets() would probably be it, but I was more looking for if anyone has a reference guide online (rather than printed book) that helps with the commands. Much like the DelphiBasics website

Comment: There's basically nothing that's different or special about OS X from the perspective of command-line programming. A general tutorial on UNIX programming will do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck; OS X provides a manual page on all (nearly all?) standard C functions; the only trouble is knowing which function provides the services you're looking for. The [`fgets()` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fgets.3.html) is probably best for reading a line-at-a-time. You'll use it something like this:

```
char buffer[MAXLINE];
if (fgets(buffer, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
    /* handle line in buffer */
}
```

If you're really looking for a *tutorial*, [The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) is one of the finest possibilities. Be sure to get the second edition -- a first edition might be entertaining, but the language has changed too drastically for it to be a reliable guide.

If you want a reference, then your manpages are the best source of information.